# Quantum measurement on Bloch Sphere

Tags: quantum-state

I'm reading the paper "[Data re-uploading for a universal quantum classifier](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.02085.pdf)".

This paper proposes the classification process as follows

1. $x_i $ with different rotation angle $\theta_i$
2. mapping the output (measurements) $\psi_{output}$ to the class (C). I will denote it as $\psi_{output:C}$ (the notation in the paper is somewhat different.)
3. Set the loss function as the -$\mathcal{F}(\psi_{output},\psi_{output:C})$. Then minimize it.

Here, because I'm used to measure the qubits with projective measurement (measurement with scalar value), I think that the $\psi_{output}$ will be measured in the projected forms. Therefore, I want to know there is any measurement process to get the $\psi_{output}$ which can be adopted the above procedure?

Comment: Add a link to the paper please.

Comment: I have edited it now!